# Check if more than two hours has passed

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'm looking for an easy way to see if more than two hours has passed between two dates.  I can either do this with a MySQL DATETIME value, or if needed, I can convert that to a UNIX timestamp. I just need an easy way to to compare those two dates and see if more than 2 hours has passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to look into [DATEDIFF](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp) function in MySQL.

Comment: Why not link to the [official MySQL documentation of DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)?

Comment: compared to official one, w3school is easier for beginners to understand.

Comment: Sometimes W3Schools has a much more simplified explanation and examples of language methods. In this example, W3Schools page = simple and straightforward. MySQL doc = HUGE wall of text and function examples.

Answer (score 3):

A UNIX timestamp is just the number of seconds that have elapsed since 12:00AM UTC, January 1, 1970.

Two hours in seconds is `60 * 60 * 2 = 7200`. So,

```
 if($secondTimestamp - $firstTimestamp >= 7200)
 {
      echo '2 hours have elapsed.';
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged with php, you could use PHP's DateTime::diff ([DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)) to get a diff between two datetime objects. I guess it depends on where in your application you are doing the comparison.

Comment: MySQL DATEDIFF function should be faster than PHP DateTime::diff calls.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP

```
  $time = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1); //this will give difference in seconds between two dates

  if(($time/3600) >= 2) { // 2 hours has left }
```